# Calculus, specifically deriving the rule for exponents

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was watching the MIT lectures series on calculus 1(https://youtu.be/9v25gg2qJYE?t=29m19s), at 29minutes and 19 seconds he converts a^x to base e by e^((log(a))^x)

Why does he convert base a to base e by raising e to the power of the constant log(a)?

Sorry if the answer is obvious, I've searched all over and can't seem to figure out why he did this.

Comment: Are you sure its not $a^x=(e^{\log(a)})^x$ instead of $e^{(\log(a))^x}$?

Comment: nevermind I just realized how stupid i was 

the e and log cancel each other out!

Comment: **Please** do not vandalize questions.

Comment: Sorry, how do I delete the question I realized my error

Comment: We do not delete questions which have already been answered.

Answer (score 2):

I havent watched the video yet but the following holds generally in logarithms

$$ e^{\ln a} = a$$

So assuming natural logs

$$ \left(e^{\ln a}\right)^x = e^{x\ln a} = e^{\ln a^x}= a^x$$

Comment: You may select an answer, by clicking the green tick mark.

Answer (score 1):

It holds that $\log_a a^x=x$. It is a known property.